# Подсветка ячеек в таблице

Tags: jquery, html, html5, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток!
Помогите с ТЗ...
Есть таблица. В каждой ячейке по изображению. надо что бы при клике на ячейку она подсвечивалась. При клике на другую ячейку подсветка переходила к новой ячейке а в старой пропадала.
Уже сутки думаю как это реализовать но потерять фокус у меня не получается...

Comment: класс меняй и все

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переключай активный класс:

CSS:

```
.clickable > tbody > tr > td.active {
  background: red;
    color: black;
}
```

Html:

```
<table class="clickable">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>a</td><td>d</td><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>a</td><td>d</td><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>a</td><td>d</td><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>a</td><td>d</td><td>a</td></tr>
</table>
```

Js:

```
$('.clickable > tbody > tr > td').click(function() {    
//добавить класс себе, убрать у других элементов в этой же таблице
  $(this).addClass('active').parents('.clickable').children('tbody').find('> tr > td.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/fLXZD/)

Comment: Только по-моему вы перепутали строку и ячейку таблицы. Думаю, что всё-таки [так будет точнее](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/fLXZD/1/) по задаче ТС.

Comment: о точно, сек

Comment: поправил, заодно селекторы точнее сделал

Comment: @eicto спасибо помогли

Answer (score 1):

Задай `class` своим строкам `tr`, и используй либо `css с :hover т.е. .myLine:hover { background-color: #eef; }` либо `jQuery` по такому же принципу, например `$(".myLine").click(function() { $(this).attr({'backgroundColor': '#eef'}) });` вот как-то так. Надеюсь, тебе это поможет. Здесь есть примеры originalip.ru, но если для тебя это не просто, зайди в jquery-docs.ru и задай в поиске `attr` сайт выдаст тебе то, что тебе нужно в доступном формате.